# How can I make positive constraint for output prediction ? - (Neural Network regression)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, regression, constraints

I am dealing with regression in Neural Networks.

The output variable should be positive,

and, of course, my output variables of training sets and test sets are positive.

I got a high accurate model but some of the predictions are negative.

Although I know this may happen, I want to make it generate only positive.

What I searched and thought were 1) ReLU activation layer after the output layer,

or 2) logarithmic scaling output variable before training (and rescale back for later analysis).

But two methods are not good...

Are there any other methods for the positive constraint on NN regression prediction?

**

Nothing is special about the code.

I m just using a sequential and regression scheme.

4 features and 1 output.

neurons change between 1~100 and hidden layers between 1~10

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(4,)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_hidden,activation="relu"))
...
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.001)
model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer=optimizer,metrics=['mae', 'mse'])
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.